# Strategy for very small dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, cross-validation, evaluation

My dataset has 640 points.
I am working on multi-class classification problem (3 classes)
For some cases, the data is imbalanced significantly (1 minority class)
for other, its balanced

What will be the best strategy to split the dataset and evaluate the model
I have read on LeaveoneOut and LeavePOut, but just wanted to know if there are some other non-conventional strategies as well.

Comment: This site is for more programming-oriented questions, you should probably ask it on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice article about [Sampling Algorithms](https://mlwhiz.com/blog/2019/07/30/sampling/). Also, sometimes the answer quite depends on what kind of business problem you are working on.